# Java transform XSLT

Tags: java, transform, xls

I have to transform xml file according to xls file and I use `javax.xml.transform.*` but this approach has limitations. I can't use xsl with a size larger than more 64kB. [GregorSamsa](https://products.technia.com/app/docs/tvc-documentation-2016.3.1/tvc/FAQ.html#xslt). 
Is there any a library in java to transform according to xsl > 64kB?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33399697/xslt-to-process-huge-xml-files-almost-5-gb

Comment: I'm curious, why it is not possible to modularize your stylesheet and break it up into smaller files and/or templates instead of just one bit stylesheet?

Comment: Stylesheet is delivered from the outside. External dependence.