# MYSQL - LOAD XML multiple repeating (deplicate) tags as one string

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, load

Problem to load multiple repeating tags "`<image></image>`" with data to one `<images>` table cell.

XML

```
<posts>
   <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <type>post</type>
      <url>www.url.com/1</url>
      <date>2016-06-15</date>
      <image>some url/1xxx.jpg</image>
      <image>some url/1yyy.jpg</image>
      <image>some url/1zzz.jpg</image>
   </item>
   <item>
      <id>2</id>
      <type>post</type>
      <url>www.url.com/2</url>
      <date>2016-06-12</date>
      <image>some url/2xxx.jpg</image>
      <image>some url/2yyy.jpg</image>
      <image>some url/2zzz.jpg</image>
      <image>some url/2www.jpg</image>
   </item>
   <item>
      <id>3</id>
      <type>post</type>
      <url>www.url.com/3</url>
      <date>2016-06-12</date>
      <image>some url/3fff.jpg</image>
   </item>
</posts>
```

Code

Now it loads only last `<image>` tag from `<item>`

```
LOAD XML local infile 'D:\\demo.xml' 
REPLACE 
INTO TABLE posts CHARACTER SET UTF8
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<item>'
(@id, @type, @url, @date, @image)
SET id=@id, type=@type, url=@url, date = str_to_date(@date, '%Y-%m'), images=@image;
```

How to store all duplicate `<image>` tags as images VARCHAR or TEXT

Comment: which is fair enough since you have only one image column but you have several images! YOur original data isn't normalized. So this is going to be trickty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider transforming your XML with [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) to normalize the `item` and `images` into one-to-many tables. Below uses PHP to run XSLT but most general purpose languages can run XSLT 1.0 scripts including PHP, Perl, Python, Java, C#, VB. Specifically, the transformation will break `<image>` tags out of `<item>` keeping corresponding `<id>` and maintain two sets of tags to upload to two MySQL database tables.

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/posts">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item/image"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name()!='image']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item/image">
    <images>
      <itemid><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::item/id"/></itemid>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </images>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP** Script

```php
<?php

$cd = dirname(__FILE__);

// LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->load('Original.xml');

$xslfile = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xslfile->load('XSLT_Script.xsl');

// TRANSFORM XML with XSLT
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xslfile); 
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// SAVE TO FILE
file_put_contents('Output.xml', $newXml);

?>
```

**Output** *(images contain item id)*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<posts>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <type>post</type>
    <url>www.url.com/1</url>
    <date>2016-06-15</date>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>2</id>
    <type>post</type>
    <url>www.url.com/2</url>
    <date>2016-06-12</date>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>3</id>
    <type>post</type>
    <url>www.url.com/3</url>
    <date>2016-06-12</date>
  </item>
  <images>
    <itemid>1</itemid>
    <image>some url/1xxx.jpg</image>
  </images>
  <images>
    <itemid>1</itemid>
    <image>some url/1yyy.jpg</image>
  </images>
  <images>
    <itemid>1</itemid>
    <image>some url/1zzz.jpg</image>
  </images>
  <images>
    <itemid>2</itemid>
    <image>some url/2xxx.jpg</image>
  </images>
  <images>
    <itemid>2</itemid>
    <image>some url/2yyy.jpg</image>
  </images>
  <images>
    <itemid>2</itemid>
    <image>some url/2zzz.jpg</image>
  </images>
  <images>
    <itemid>2</itemid>
    <image>some url/2www.jpg</image>
  </images>
  <images>
    <itemid>3</itemid>
    <image>some url/3fff.jpg</image>
  </images>
</posts>
```

**SQL** *(two tables to upload)*

```sql
-- POSTS TABLE
LOAD XML local infile 'C:\\Path\\To\\Output.xml' 
REPLACE 
INTO TABLE posts CHARACTER SET UTF8
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<item>'
(@id, @type, @url, @date)
SET id=@id, type=@type, url=@url, date=str_to_date(@date, '%Y-%m');

-- IMAGES TABLE    
LOAD XML local infile 'C:\\Path\\To\\Output.xml' 
REPLACE 
INTO TABLE images CHARACTER SET UTF8
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<images>'
(@itemid, @image)
SET itemid=@itemid, image=@image;
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait, great post. It works. But I have another problem using XSLT, my XML files up to 1 GB size. I cut my file in 50 tymes and still have "Memory allocation failed"( But for small files it works like a charm.

Comment: Yes, XSLT works great on smaller files but is a memory hog with larger ones as it reads in entire document before processing. Some XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 have streaming processes but these require external extensions. Consider slicing larger files and looping with PHP to import into MySQL.

Comment: Typically, you need a [RAM about 5 times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101048/xslt-transformation-on-large-xml-files-with-c-sharp) the size of a file for XSLT.